# When is $f_{xy}(x,y)\neq f_{yx}(x,y)?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When is $f_{xy}(x,y)\neq f_{yx}(x,y)?$, where $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ denote the mixed (second) partial derivatives of a multivariable function $z=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Wiki has an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth studying the following results:

Schwartz Theorem or Young Theorem or Clairault Theorem.

And see examples where $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$ to see what happens (or not happens!).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they are different when one or both of the mixed second partial derivatives does not exist or is not continuous in f(x,y)'s domain.

Comment: You can check an answer I submitted earlier that might clarify things :[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751635/prove-that-f-xy-f-yx/751659#751659)

Answer (score 0):

A well known theorem in multi-variable calculus is, mixed partial derivative of the **twice differentiable functions with continuous partial derivative up to second order**, will commute.

But if this condition is removed, many counter example can be found even the function is twice differentiable, consider

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x_1^2x_2(x_1-x_2)}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \text{if}\quad (x_1,x_2)\neq (0,0)\\ 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\text{if}\quad (x_1,x_2)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

One can show that all second order partial derivative exists everywhere (even exist at (0,0) by first principle). But mixed derivative at (0,0) not equal.