# Prove that $f'_{xy}=f'_{yx}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is a basic, and probably a bad, question. A fundamental rule of derivatives.

Why is $f'_{xy}=f'_{yx}$ true?

Comment: this is not alwayss true. check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: I'm in my fist multivariable calculus course (second semester of calculus).

Comment: @jacob And despite this, it remains false in many cases.

Comment: I know what $f_{xy}$ is, and I know what $f'$ is, but I don't know what you mean by $f'_{xy}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well this needs two assumptions: That you are working on an open set, and the second partial derivatives are continuous. This is usually proven using the mean value theorem, however here is an interesting proof using Fubini's theorem. Notation $D_{2,1}=f_{yx}$ and $D_{1,2}=f_{xy}$

Assume $D_{1,2}f(a)-D_{2,1}f(a)>0$ at some point  (i.e they are not equal, the case the difference is negative can be handled similarly). By continuity there is a neighbourhood $A=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ on which $D_{1,2}f(x)-D_{2,1}f(x)>0$, for $x \in A$ $$\int_{A}D_{2,1}f=\int_{c}^d\int_a^b D_{2,1}f dxdy=\int_{c}^d D_1f(b,y)-D_1(a,y)dy= \\f(b,d)-f(a,d)-f(b,c)+f(a,c) $$

Similarly  $\int_{A}D_{2,1}f=\int_{a}^b\int_c^d D_{1,2}f dydx = f(b,d)-f(b,c)-f(a,d)+f(a,c)$.

Then $\int_{A}D_{1,2}f-D_{2,1}f=0$ which is a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

This is a formal proof of the Schwarz Theorem:
Let $ \omega$ be a neighbourhood of (0,0) such that for every (h,k) of $\omega$, $(a+h, b+k)$ is within U (where $f$ is defined).
Let:
$$ F(h,k)=f(a+h,b+h)-f(a+h,b)-f(a,b+k)+f(a,b)$$

And, let's consider the function 
$$ \phi(x) = f(x,b+k) - f(x,b) $$

We have:
 $$\phi(x+k) - \phi(x)= f(x+h,b+k) - f(x+h,b)- f(x,b+k)+ f(x,b) $$
Thus $$ F(h,k)= \phi(a+h) - \phi(a) $$

Let's derive $\phi(x)$ with respect to x:

$$\phi'(x)= f'_x(x,b+k)- f'_x(x,b)$$

Using the Mean value theorem you can prove that there exists an $\alpha$ between 0 and 1 such that :
$$ \phi(x+h) - \phi(x) = h\phi'(x+ \alpha h)$$
Thus :
$$F(h,k) = h[f'_x(a+ \alpha h,b+k) - f'_x(a+\alpha h,b)]$$

But the function $f'_x(a +\alpha h,y)$ is differentiable. Applying the mean value theorem again shows that there exists a $\beta$ between 0 and 1 such that:

$$F(h,k)= hkf"_{xy}(a+\alpha h,b + \beta k)$$

And since $f"_{xy}$ is continuous at (a,b):

$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{F(h,k)}{hk} = \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}f"_{xy}(a+ \alpha h, b + \beta k)= f"_{xy}(a,b) $$

Now, let $\Psi(y)$ such that:
$$\Psi(y) = f(a+h,y)-f(a,y)$$

Applying the same demonstration as before, we find that:
$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{F(h,k)}{hk} = \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}f"_{yx}(a+ \alpha h, b + \beta k)= f"_{yx}(a,b) $$

Which finally leads to :

$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{F(h,k)}{hk} = f"_{xy}(a,b)= f"_{yx}(a,b) $$

(After Leila Richa's lectures at the ULFG-II)

Comment: Plus, the two second derivatives must exist and be continuous in order for the theorem to be true.

Comment: You need the set to be open to guarantee $(a+h,b+k)$ remains in the set. You should start by saying let $h,k$ be small enough so that $(a+h,b+k)$ remains in the set. The existence of such $h,k$ is due to the set being open.

Comment: Exactly, forgot to mention that. My Bad. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: @user10444 Done.